# Setting a dropdowns values based on a different model selection

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I currently have a model with 2 fields:
*Name & Number of Units*

When the first field is selected `e.g. Name = Name1` I would like to display the Number Of Units saved in association with that model. `e.g. Name1 has 50 units` then the second < select > will show the number a list from 1 - 50 because Name1 has 50 units.

When I do this with my code currently , it lists the max number of units for every model entry instead

Please see the below code:

**template.html:**

```
<form>
    <select  name="Complex">
        {% for x in model %}
            <option value="{{ x }}">{{ x.ComplexName }}</option>
        {%  endfor %}
    </select>> Complex


    <select>
        {% for x in model %}
            <option value="{{ x.NumberOfUnits }}">{{ x.NumberOfUnits }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>

</form>
```

**Views.py:**

```
def customerDetails(request):
    model = ComplexListClass.objects.all().order_by('ComplexName')

    content = {'model': model}
    return render(request, 'main/customerDetails.html', content)
```

**Models.py:**

```
class ComplexListClass(models.Model):
    ComplexName = models.CharField(choices=complex_list , max_length =  50 ,default='1' , unique=True)
    NumberOfUnits = models.IntegerField(max_length=2 , blank=False , default=1 )

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.ComplexName)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to go down the AJAX route, I'd suggest adding the maximum number of units to the first `<select>` and making the `NumberOfUnits` an Integer input field (with a minimum value validator of 1?). Form validation can further check that the number is not greater than the number available, which the user was already told about. Raise a validation error about exceeding the maximum.

```
<form>
<select  name="Complex">
    {% for x in model %}
        <option value="{{ x }}">
            {{ x.ComplexName }} ({{ x.NumberOfUnits }} available </option>
    {%  endfor %}
</select>> Complex

{{form.number_of_units}}
```

and in your form override the `clean` method to check

```
    def clean(self):
        #get clean values from the form
        cleaned_data=super().clean()

        complex_name = cleaned_data['ComplexName')

        # t.b.s. get the maximum_units for this name here 

        if cleaned_data['NumberOfUnits'] > maximum_units:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                f"Only {maximum_units} available for {complex_name}" )
        return cleaned_data
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Django goes to sleep between request, you cannot have it serve different values based on a selection(even though it looks very simple and a much in use scenario).. So you will have to use a way around like passing the dropdown values as **AJAX** if you want to dynamically show the dropdown options...

The below link shows an easy implementation of what you are looking for,

[Django chained dropdowns](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html)